# Download manager does not recognise .mp3 files

Tags: android, download-manager

I am using Download Manager 
and i want to download some audio files using my own webview.

I use the following code:

```
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url2));
        request.setDescription("Downloading");
        request.setTitle("File :");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        }
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "audio.mp3");
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
```

Even if the the File Name is audio.mp3 download manager does not recongise the file type.
ScreenShot explains the main problem.

[image]

Using other apps like default browser downloaded files look like this!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple:
Just add the following line

```
request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");
```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setMimeType(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

not work : request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");

To operate, follow the steps below.

request.setMimeType("audio/mpeg");